# jquery Add a Table Row, Remove a Table row. Max 10 rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview in a .aspx page that gets its rows from another page that is called.  This other page returns a single table row (tr) as a result from an SQL query.  This happens every second.

The new rows are added to the top of the table/gridview.

I need to limit the number of row to a number, say 10.  My code so far (mostly found by examples here at Stackoverflow) works pretty well, except when the table gets to 10 rows, it will flicker the 9th and 10th rows.  i.e. it will show 9 rows, then 10 rows, then 9 rows and so on as it loads.

Ideally, it would add rows up to 10 then as new rows are added the 10th, or last, row drops off without any flickering.  It would be more 'fluid' so-to-speak.  As if you are scrolling.

All examples I have found delete rows as a result of a button click.  I need to table/gridview to grow up to 10, then as new rows are added, the last row drops off.

I hope this makes sense.

Any suggestions on how I could improve this?  Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  f1();
  function f1() {  // gridView updated every 1000ms
    jq(document).ready(function () {
      var lastid = jq.cookie("maxid");  // set by pageInit
      if (lastid != "0")
        jq.get("page2.aspx", function (dataReturned) {
          if (dataReturned != "")    // rows in database - add to the gridView 
          {
            // add new row
            jq('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr:first').after(dataReturned);
            // hide the new row, then fade it back in ----  tr:eq(0) is the header row.

            jq('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr:eq(1)').hide().fadeIn(1000, function () { 
                  // nop
                }).css('display', 'table-row');
          }
          window.setTimeout("f1()", 1000);
        });
      else
        jq.get("page2.aspx", function (dataReturned) {
          if (dataReturned != "")     //new rows in database 
          {
            jq('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').html(dataReturned);
          }
          window.setTimeout("f1()", 1000);
        });
    });
       LimitRows();
    }

  function LimitRows(){
    while (jq('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr').length > '10')
     {
       jq('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:last').remove();
    }      }    
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you reading the cookie value `maxid` every time you call `f1()` function? Also, what is the difference between `page2.aspx` and `gv2.aspx`? Finally, why are you calling the `LimitRows()` function even if no new rows were added, shouldn't the check for exceeding 10 rows only happen when you have added something?

Comment: Karl, gv2.aspx should have read page2.aspx - typo on my part.  maxid tells me if my sql resulted in a new record.  Maybe calling LimitRows as I am now is the problem(?).  This is a learning process for me.  Maybe my approach is wrong, but I am learning. Thank you.